# WooCommerce stock per attribute

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a technical problem with the WooCommerce plugin that I can't seem to find an answer for.
I got a variable product that has two different times for workshops. 
So an example to simplify:

Product: Event day ticket

Workshop 1: Red | Blue | Green

Workshop 2: Red | Blue | green

On workshop 1, every attribute needs to have 5 stock but on workshop 2 every attribute needs to have 10 stock.

I can make combination variables but if I do that, every combination has it's own stock. Not the attribute itself.

Any idea on how to work with issue?

I hope I explained it well enough.

Comment: Why isn't variation level stock management sufficient? Workshop 1/Red = 5 stock. Workshop 2/Red = 10 stock.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Yeah, I know that's what OP wants, but I'm still asking _why_ because it doesn't make a lot of sense to me. :) Variation level stock management seems perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Because if you set a stock on variations, you get a stock for the combination itself not the actual "Red" selection. Which would bring various problems.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into something similar and the answer is a Variable Product with addons (one option is WooCommerce's own plugin @ https://woocommerce.com/products/product-add-ons/). You'd create Workshop as a variable attribute, then create product variations and set each Workshop's total number of tickets in the variations. Then create product addons for Red, Blue, and Green (you can set the cost of addons to any value including 0). That should give you the result you're seeking.

Answer (score -1):

Attributes define available "options" (like colors as you have it) but you need to set the product to be a *variable* product (the default is *simple* product) using the dropdown at the top of that configuration section. Then, on the attributes section, check the box to use the attributes as variations. Finally, on the variations tab, create the variations from attributes.

Now, you can set stock levels, prices, and more for each *variation* of the product where a *variation* is a single or combination of attributes.

**Note:** You may need to go into the Woocommerce settings and check the box to manage inventory at the variation level. This is from memory so I don't recall if it's in the Woocommerce settings or an option when you switch the product to variable.

Comment: I know how a variable product works. But I need to find a solution on how to manage the stock on attribute choice level.

If I were to make variations of every combination I would be able to order (Looking at my example) Red from Workshop 1, 15 times due to being able to making different combinations. 

I'm sorry if I'm being confusing but it's not very easy to explain.